# Scratch on wall - ceramic tile

Tags: bathroom, repair, walls, ceramic-tile

by accident I scratch ceramic tile in my bathroom while cleaning. Do you have any idea how can I remove/(paint?)/fix this?

I tried a lot of home products (at start I though its just a tech pencil), but without result.

Wall specification: https://www.paradyz.com/en/catalog/elia/elia-bianco-sciana-struktura-rekt

**Scratch:**
[image]

**EDIT**: Thanks for all the answers, I'm going to try them soon. I will let you know about the results.

Comment: Are you sure that's a scratch? If you drag your fingernail across it does it catch or remove the mark?

Comment: I tried scrub with a sponge, "magic sponge", pencil eraser and some other home stuff. It not changing at all. Maybe this is somehow like metal trail, but when I drag my finger across I don't feel this mark.

Comment: Maybe try a mild abrasive cleaner or conventional toothpaste.

Comment: Toothpaste without any result.

Comment: Tile and grout cleaner/haze remover, like an acid wash?

Comment: If it is a scratch You can not "remove" it by scrubbing or other means of cleaning. A scratch is portion of the surface that has been removed thereby exposing the material under it.

Answer (score 3):

Try alkyd (oil-based) paint. Yes, paint. If the tile off white and if you have a scrap somewhere, take it to a paint store and they can sell you a match. The crack will disappear or only you will know.

Answer (score 3):

Metal marks can sometimes be removed with lacquer thinner or acetone. Try a cloth dampened on a corner with the solvent. I have had some good results on similar looking marred tile.

Comment: I have had much success with lacquer thinner on removing all sorts of marks on surfaces

Answer (score 3):

In the past I have "borrowed" some nail polish from my wife that was a similar hue. I then, painted over it with a ceramic tile gloss (you can buy it at any home improvement store) and set it with a hair dryer (even better a heat gun, as stated above on low, if you have one). It worked and no one knew it was there unless you knew exactly where to look.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 1):

Try a white wax crayon like from a kid's art kit. Or a white wax putty stick; the type used for furniture scratch repair. Rub it all along the crack, rub off excess gently with a rag, then heat a bit with a blow dryer or heat gun (on low setting).